# Comparing two Any values

Tags: ios, swift, casting, compare, any

I have a use case that I need to compare two `Any` values that I don't know the type.

```swift
// assuming I have something like:
var myDict = [
  "a": "one",
  "b": 2,
  "c": false
]
var newDict = [
  "a": "one",
  "c": true
]

func updateDict() -> Bool {
  var hasChanged = false
  newDict.forEach { (key: String, value: Any) in
    if myDict[key] != value {
      hasChanged = true
    }
    myDict[ket] = value
  }
  return hasChanged
}
```

How can I achieve that since `if myDict[key] != value` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

for now what I did is:

```swift
if let oldValue = values[key] {
    changed = (String(describing: oldValue) != String(describing: value))
} else {
    changed = true
}
```

It's not perfect, but kind of works for what I need

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`isEqual(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary/1415445-isequal) which is defined on `NSDictionary`:

```
var myDict: [String : Any] = [
    "a": "one",
    "b": 2,
    "c": false
    ]

var newDict: [String : Any] = [
    "a": "one",
    "c": true
]

NSDictionary(dictionary: myDict).isEqual(to: newDict)  // false
```